# using Image as an event trigger with jquery, html and css

Tags: jquery, html, image, button

i im developing a proyect web site with css, jquery and html. what happens is that in the html, i have a table with only 3 columns and i'm placing images to use as buttoms to toggle the content below the buttom. Here's the code:

```
<table id='buttom-service'>
            <tr>
                <td class="selectors">
                    <img src="images/icon1.png" id='ser_bt1'alt="Radiocomunicacion" />
                </td>
                <td class="selectors">
                    <img src="images/icon2.png" id='ser_bt2' alt="Arquitectura" />
                </td>
                <td class="selectors">
                    <img src="images/icon3.png" id='ser_bt3' alt="Radiocomunicacion"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Now, I make the images to work as buttoms with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //default load
   $('#buttom-service').addClass('hover');

   //action buttoms
   $('#ser_bt1').click(function(){
    do stuff;

   });
   $('#ser_bt2').click(function(){
    do stuff;

   });
   $('#ser_bt3').click(function(){
    do stuff

   });});
```

The problem with this is that the clicable area in the first 2 images is reduced to the lower part of the image and not the whole thing, while the third element works fine. (they toggle the content fine btw)
I need some advice on how to make the three images work as buttoms properly. (the clicable area)

thank you

Comment: `$('.selectors').click(function(){ var id = $(this).children('img').prop('id'); do stuff; });` does the same, but click is binded to the cells, witch have equal height

Answer (score 0):

What about...?

```
$('#ser_bt1,#ser_bt2,#ser_bt3').closest('.selectors').on('click',function(){
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: alright im going to try that. But can you xplain me a little bit of the .closest() and .on() methods? im still learning jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using button tags instead. Attach the click listener to the button and set the image as a background for the button in css.

Comment: Tried that and still occurs the same thing. somehow the clicable area is reduced to the lower part. Discovered that this happens to every bttn but in the last one.